# scope not persisting when changing views

Tags: angularjs

Here is my controller...

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('funApp')
      .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.choice = null;
        $scope.addQuestionFeedback = '';
        $scope.questions = [];
        $scope.questions = [
            {
                question: "What is your favorite color",
                type: "color"
            },
            {
                question: "What is your favorite food",
                type: "food"
            }
        ];

        $scope.submit = function() {
            this.questions.push(this.addQuestion);
            $scope.addQuestionFeedback = 'Question Successfully Added!';
        }
      });
```

The issue is I have a view that calls `submit()` successfully, but when I change views, the object that I added in `submit()` does not persist and `$scope.question` goes back to initial state of having 2 objects only. How do I solve this?

Comment: Use $scope.question.push instead of this.question.push. Also, this.addQustion has to change to $scope.addQuestion if it is a scope variable or model variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MVC pattern. Services (models) hold you objects, your Controller is just kinda like an a go between between your objects and your views. Most of the work that's done is generally in your models. In angular services are persistent where as controllers get destroyed and recreated when it's no longer in use.

```
 angular.module('funApp')
      .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, questions) {
    $scope.choice = null;
    $scope.addQuestionFeedback = '';
    $scope.questions = questions.questions;

    $scope.submit = function() {
        questions.questions.push(this.AddQuestion);
        $scope.addQuestionFeedback = 'Question Successfully Added!';
    }
  })

.factory('questions', function () {
  var questions = [
        {
            question: "What is your favorite color",
            type: "color"
        },
        {
            question: "What is your favorite food",
            type: "food"
        }
    ];


  return {
    questions = questions
  }
})
```

Comment: this is the right approach. Using a service or a Factory for persistent datas through controllers.